# ROS 2 RQT error but still working

Tags: ros, ros2, rqt, ros-humble

When running rqt or rqt_graph on my ROS 2 Humble Ubuntu Jammy (22.04) System an error is printed. It says in red:

```
RosPluginProvider._parse_plugin_xml() plugin file "/home/observer/ros2_ws/install/rqt_controller_manager/share/rqt_controller_manager/plugin.xml" in package "rqt_controller_manager" not found
RosPluginProvider._parse_plugin_xml() plugin file "/home/observer/ros2_ws/install/rqt_joint_trajectory_controller/share/rqt_joint_trajectory_controller/plugin.xml" in package "rqt_joint_trajectory_controller" not found
RosPluginProvider._parse_plugin_xml() plugin file "/home/observer/ros2_ws/install/rqt_controller_manager/share/rqt_controller_manager/plugin.xml" in package "rqt_controller_manager" not found
RosPluginProvider._parse_plugin_xml() plugin file "/home/observer/ros2_ws/install/rqt_joint_trajectory_controller/share/rqt_joint_trajectory_controller/plugin.xml" in package "rqt_joint_trajectory_controller" not found
```

rqt does open up and seem to work, but I can't wrap my head around, why this message is printed. I have changed nothing that I could link to this occurrence. It just came up all of a sudden.

Hope someone could help me.